# Ninject DynamicProxyModule won't work if loaded after kernel is created

Tags: wpf, ninject, prism, castle-dynamicproxy, interception

I'm having an issue with DynamicProxyModule and Ninject. I want to load all modules that are present in the root directory of my program (without having to write copious amounts of code), but **the DynamicProxyModule doesn't work if it loaded after the Ninject Kernel is constructed**. All other modules seem to work fine. I'm using this with Prism for WPF if that makes any difference. Here is my code:

```
public class Bootstrapper : NinjectBootstrapper
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var ninjectSettings = new NinjectSettings { LoadExtensions = false };
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(ninjectSettings);
        return kernel;
    }

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        // Load modules present in all local directory dll files.
        Kernel.Load(new string[] {"*.dll"});
        // Initialize the loaded modules
        base.InitializeModules();
        // Add Service class to the IoC container
        Kernel.Bind<Service>().ToSelf();
        // Configure Ninject to intercept any call to the Service class's
        // Execute() function and replace the call with the following
        // console message
        Kernel.InterceptReplace<Service>(x => x.Execute(), invocation =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INTERCEPTION!");
        });
        // Now, request an instance of Service from the IoC container
        var service = Kernel.Get<Service>();
        // Call the Execute function, expecting it to be intercepted
        service.Execute();
    }

    // More stuff for the Bootstrapper
    // ... 
}

public class Service
{
    public virtual void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Code Executed");
    }
}
```

**Interception never happens!** However, if I change LoadExtensions to true and change the Kernel.Load() parameters to the code below, it works. **What's going on?**

```
var ninjectSettings = new NinjectSettings { LoadExtensions = true };

Kernel.Load("TestProject.*");
```

My application needs to support plugins/modules from 3rd party developers, but I won't know what the dlls will be called. I can get the dll names from the root directory or any plugins folder I create, but I was hoping there was a less verbose or more elegant way of doing it that I might have missed.

Here are the **NuGet packages** that I'm using:

- Prism for WPF with the associated Ninject packages (6.1.0)
- Ninject.Extensions.Conventions (3.2.0)
- Ninject.Extensions.Interception (3.2.0)
- Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy (3.2.0)
- Castle.Core (3.3.3)

Anyways, thank you for taking the time to read this and for any help you can give!